# Trying to find out the technical name of this step in oAuth world

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, oim

I've done this several times with Google sign in. Basically, use the token to ping Google's auth servers from my server and findout if the token is valid and validate user info.

The process is outlined here https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#verify-the-integrity-of-the-id-token

I'm trying to find out what's the technical name of this process in oAuth language. I need it for talking to people who are familiar with Oracle Identity Manager and possibly find out the endpoint in OIM that will facilitate this feature.

Can someone help me by helping with these questions?

A. The oAuth name of this process
B. OIM name or a link to the documentation which provides more info on this
C. OIM endpoints to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears you are referencing the [Verification of ID Token](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ImplicitIDTValidation) in OpenID Connect.